# Rails has_many through, grouping and summing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, grouping

I'm confused about how to group and obtain data with a has_many through relationship.  My current models look like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_items, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :ingredients, through: :project_items
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_items
end

class ProjectItem
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

This allows me to call the following from my view:

```
<%= render partial: "users/project_item", collection: @project_items, as: :ingredient %>
```

with @project_items being defined in my controller as:

```
@project_items = @user.ingredients
```

which directs to a _project_item partial that currently just outputs name and quantity and when it was created.

```
<li>
    <span class="span2"><%= ingredient.name %></span>
    <span class="span2"><%= ingredient.quantity %></span>
    <span class="span3"><%= @user.pantry_items.find_by(:ingredient_id => ingredient.id).created_at %></span>
</li>
```

This works well and outputs all the correct data.  However, the database has multiple instances of the same ingredient from different projects.  I'm looking to do the following

**1. Group by name with only the same name listed once**

If I use `@user.ingredients.group_by(&:name)` I get no results returned.  If I use `@user.ingredients.group('name') I get the following call:

```
: SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "project_items" ON "ingredients"."id" = "project_items"."ingredient_id" WHERE "project_items"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY name
```

But gives an error on the render as: *PG::Error: ERROR:  column "ingredients.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*

**2. Is it possible to add and return a column of a grouped result?** For example I have:

```
Name            Quantity

Oak 2x2             2

Oak 2x2             4
```

To return  Oak 2x2   6?

I'm guessing it would look like `@user.ingredients.select('ingredients, sum(quantity) )` but I'm not sure how to include it with the grouping and have it output correctly with my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SQL interface in ActiveRecord associations:

```
has_many :ingredients, -> { group("name").select("ingredients.*", "SUM(ingredients.quantity) AS quantity") }, through: :project_items
```

This probably needs more tweaking to get it right, and is explained more with [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins)

Comment: Is there a way to put this in a named scoped, or have it in the controller?

Comment: To allow it to be dynamic?

Comment: Yes, I don't always want the user.ingredients to be grouped with a sum quantity.

Comment: You could put it into a scope like this:

```scope :summed, ->(var) { SQL }```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot over the next few days, leaving the question open for the time being.